# How use SharedPreferences correctly flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm newbie in flutter and I would like to save data locally after login using SharedPreferences . I created a class loadUserData() for reusing data stored in SharedPreferences in other class .

Login class :

```
  Future<User> login(String email, String password) async {
    await checkInternet();

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    Map<String, String> body = {'email': email, 'password': password};

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.AUTH_LOGIN),
        headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
        var data = body['user'];
        User user = User.fromJson(data);
        Track track = Track.fromJson(body);
        if (body['code'] == 0) {
          SharedPreferences localStorage =
              await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          localStorage.setInt('id', body['user']['id']);
          localStorage.setString('adress', body['user']['adress']);
          localStorage.setString('name', body['user']['name']);
          localStorage.setString('phone', body['user']['phone']);
          localStorage.setString('access_token', body['access_token']);
        }
        return user;
      case 500:
        throw ('Erreur serveur');
        break;
      case 400:
        throw LoginFailed();
      default:
        throw ('connection timeout');
        break;
    }
  }
```

and i create loadUserData() in second file :

```
  loadUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user'));

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        name = user['name'];
        phone = user['phone'];
        adress = user['adress'];
        email = user['email'];
      });
    }
  }
```

But name , phone , adress and email  in loadUserData() are empty . How i can get data correctly ??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're setting the following keys: `id`, `address`, `name`, `phone` and `access_token` but you're trying to read the key `user`.

Also, you may want to consider [SecureStorage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) to store the access_token and other sensitive information

Comment: firstly ... i would like to get data correctly in  loadUserData() class

Comment: So instead of localStorage.getString('user'), you need to call localStorage.getString('name'), localStorage.getString('phone') etc.